# FileBeat directly to ELS or via LogStash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

We are installing ELS and Kibana for log aggregation/analysis.  The first system to use it is greenfield so we output structured logs from the services that make up our system.  Given that we don't need to add structure to our logs I was planning on using FileBeat to ship the logs directly to ELS and not use LogStash.  Is this a sensible option or does LogStash have value over and above parsing that we might need? If we do use LogStash can I use that to harvest log files or should I still use FileBeat to pump the logs to LogStash?

Answer (score 15):

Logstash is useful if you need to aggregate logs from many servers and apply some common transformations and filtering to your events.

If your log events are already structured and you are ok with indexing them directly, then you can definitely have Filebeat send them directly to ES. If ES goes down (e.g. for maintenance), Filebeat will retry until it can successfully send the events.

Comment: Note for an unlimited tries, you have to set the line `max_retries: -1` in your config `filebeat.yml` otherwise it'll try only 3 times and terminate (default value = 3). In our config we also have a Redis which act as a buffer, but the option is still useful even for that case (redis can also go down).

Answer (score 7):

> Is this a sensible option or does LogStash have value over and above parsing that we might need?

Deciding to use Logstash or not, in your case, depends on whether you need to treat the logs before inserting them into ES.

In addition to parsing (which is apparently useless in your use case), you can use Logstash to add a location with the [geoip filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-geoip.html), parse a date with the [date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html), [replace a word with another](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html), [replace a field with a hash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-anonymize.html), etc...

You can have a look at the available filters [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html).

> If we do use LogStash can I use that to harvest log files or should I still use FileBeat to pump the logs to LogStash?

If you need Logstash and can afford to run it on the machine where your logs are, you can avoid using Filebeat, by using the file input.

But keep in mind that Logstash, especially if used for parsing, can consume a lot of resources. It is better to have it on another machine and use Filebeat to pump the logs to Logstash.