# filebeat to logstash or elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I'm trying to visualize logs from my app. My logs formatted as json and stored in some file. I have filebeat installed which uses the same file as input. An filebeat could send the logs to Logstash and to Elasticsearch directly. Logstash could process logs, do something, parse them...
But my logs are json formatted already.

Elasticsearch are going to be installed on another server, another side of the planet...

so, my question is, Is there any good reason to use logstash in such scenario?( no need do any processing ), or is it ok to send logs to elasticsearch server directly?

I'm guessing the Logstash could do some buffering, but I want to keep my app's server light, don't want to install anything on top of it.

Thanks.

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873791/filebeat-directly-to-els-or-via-logstash/39874014#39874014

Comment: I got you... Post as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: The answer is already there, you can simply upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

May this help you :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html.
You can post the json into es by filebeat without Logstash, Logtstash is too heavy sometimes.